# Get the opposite of lemma in wordnet

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I am looking for the opposite of `getLemma()` for wordnet.

From the base form of a verb for example "be", I want the various forms such as "is" and "are". Is it possible to get to those using Extended Java WordNet Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **morphological generator** takes lemma as input and provides a list of morphological variants. Check [Catvar](http://clipdemos.umiacs.umd.edu/catvar/), for example.

Princeton WordNet has limited morphology analysis. Even so, [Morphy](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/morphy.7WN.html) can be easily modified to return more than the existing dictionary forms.